# Updating existing database with values from external files (csv/xml or sql script)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have a project on ASP.NET MVC 5 (C#) with Entity Framework 6 and an existing DB generated with code first. Also I have a class for initial seeding with some values. I use ASP identity system for authentication if it matters.

Now I need to add some data to my DB. I have an csv/xml/sql files (with the same data exported from another DB) and I need to configure the seeding process manually (probably using linq?) because the data structure in these external files differes from my model. So I need to seed with manual mapping of properties.

For example. These external files with exporeted data are just having a User table with string properties: "Name", "Group" and so on. But my model have a Group as a seperate table with it's properties and User is just having a reference property for Group.
There're more cases like that, so I need to select the data from any of these external files to be able to handle it with custom logic that I will add later.

Comment: Parse data from files to your entities. Then save entities to your database

Comment: What @SergeyBerezovskiy said! In case you have lots of data, it might be efficient to use SQL or any database backup/replication mechanism to do this.